# Question about conditional

Tags: conditionals

I'm referring to Benidorm, Season 2, Episode 1 (Jacqueline):

This structure:

> If it were me who had picked up that ******, I wouldn't have come
>   back.

This sentence sounds (and looks) strange. I am used to standard 2nd and 3rd, as well as mixed, conditionals.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Massimo

Is this a non-defining relative clause in the past perfect, dropped into the middle of a 2nd/3rd mixed conditonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatically fine: I can't see anything strange about it.

And yes, there is a **defining** relative clause in there; it modifies the NP "me".